# Pop-up message after progress bar completes?

Tags: android

hey..hi..please tell me if i want to show pop-up message after completing my progress bar which is on 1st activity. now i have created progress bar its runs but remaining part i want to show pop-message as progress bar reached the max. limit....please help me out

Comment: You should change the title to something that relates to the question.

Comment: This is your 7th question on this site, and you've used "Hi,Android developers" as the subject of every single one of them! Please learn to write a meaningful topic (the edits to your previous questions should give you an idea on what to work towards).

Comment: ok....i will do it....as i am new on this forum....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)?

(You may also want to change the title of this submission to something more relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getProgress%28%29

and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getMax%28%29

You can write something like

```
if (yourBar.getProgress() == yourBar.getMax()) do something
```